# sizing unity window issue when running as VM under virtualbox

Tags: unity, virtualbox, virtualization

installed ubuntu on VM (virtualBox).  How do I get the right screensize without losing real estate from the ununtu desktop within the vm virtualbox window.  Can't see the full desktop.

Comment: You will need to [install Virtual Box Guest Additions][1] to be able to do that.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm/22745#22745

Answer (score 1):

Start your Virtual Machine

Select 'View' in menu bar

Select 'Auto resize guest display' option

Install Guest Additions and Extension Pack.

Also, if you installed Virtualbox from the software center, uninstall it and get the latest version from here: virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Auto re-size guest display or hitting the host+G keys, is dimmed out so I cannot select it.  How does one get the option available?  Thanks!!

Comment: Install Guest Additions and Extension Pack.  Also, if you installed Virtualbox from the software center, uninstall it and get the latest version from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads